# Spring Data JPA - Insert into set dynamically

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I'm using JPA repositories in my project.
I would like insert into the DB some set elements.

The Standard way of doing so is:

```
 MyObject myObject = this.myRepository.findOne(id);
 // for each new element:
 myObject.getSetOfElements().add(newElements[i]);
 this.myRepository.save(myObject);
```

I would like to insert these new elements via a dynamically created query and execute it (without the getting myObject first as above).

Is it possible to do so with spring data?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you give an example to what you're trying to accomplish? what do you mean by "dynamically created query ?